# Trigger a ZSH function when a command calls for sudo password

Tags: zsh, sudo, notifications

I quite often run into a situation where a long running system upgrade gets stuck on getting a `sudo` password, most often because the time for the last input has expired and I simply forgot about the update process running on some remote workspace nr 8 or 9. This is the case for example when using `yay` to build and upgrade AUR packages.

I don't want to set those commands to not require password for security reasons. I also don't want to increase the expiration time. Ideally I would have a system notification or an audio beep saying that something is waiting for password. How would I do it in ZSH?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to run the update in a root shell instead?

But if you prefer sudo here had someone a very similar question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371712/how-do-i-make-a-terminal-beep-when-user-input-is-required

The sudo command also has a `--bell` option which kinda fits your use case but I doubt it works here because other tools will not add this option.

Comment: AUR fetches and builds packages which should not be run in the root shell (most of the tools for this even refuse to run as root).